# How to show data returned from ajax call in a modal box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to return data of another page and I just get one time.

The result is just for the first, i think the ajax is correct because in the console the data is correct but when will be insert in the modal it happen this error.

**PHP:**

```
$sql = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users ORDER by registred DESC");                      
$sql->bind_param("i", $_SESSION["userid"]);
$sql->execute();
$res = $sql->get_result();
if($res->num_rows) {
  while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "
    <div id='myModal' class='modal fade' role='dialog'>
      <div class='modal-dialog'>
        <div class='modal-content'>
          <div class='modal-header'>
            <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal'>&times;</button>
            <h4 class='modal-title'> Data from user </h4>
          </div>
          <div class='modal-body' id='add_link_".base64_encode($row["id"])."'>
          </div>
          <div class='modal-footer'>
            <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'> Close </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    ";
  }
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
   function att(id){
     $.get("ajax.php?i="+id, function( data ) {
       console.log(id);
       $("#add_link_" +id).html("");
       if($("#add_link_" +id).html(data)) {
         console.log(data);
         $('#myModal').modal('show');
       }
     });
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Where/when are you calling `att(id)` function? Is it being called? Also, you are showing `#myModal` which is supposed to be unique on your page, but it is not. So, that might be the problem.

Comment: @Uzbekjon yes, i think it's the problem, #myModal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are "showing" `#myModal` which is supposed to be unique on your page, but it is not. Also, your function is not being called. But, I suppose you are calling it somewhere since you are saying that `console.log` is showing your correct data.

Basically, change your `$('#myModal').modal('show');` call to this:

```
$(this).closest('.modal').modal('show');
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, can you tell me how can i include colsest? beucase i got this error: $(...).colsest is not a function

Comment: Sorry, typo. That should be `closest`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Sorry, another typo: `.modal`. Updated the answer.

Comment: isn't work but i solve, thank you. i've set a id for class,  $('.shooow' +id).modal('show');